# Simple/Elementary derivation of Ramanujan's continued fraction for Hurwitz $\zeta(3,x+1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, elementary-proofs, continued-fractions, ramanujan

I came across this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141066/a-new-continued-fraction-for-ap%C3%A9rys-constant-zeta3) discussing a certain continued fraction for $\zeta(3)$ (more specifically, the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) $\zeta(s,z)$ at $s=3$) due to Ramanujan. I asked the original poster Tito for a reference, and he gave me [this Archived Google site link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0017), which draws from the source *[Chapter 12 of Ramanujan’s Second Notebook: Continued Fractions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-15/issue-2/Chapter-12-of-Ramanujans-second-notebook-Continued-fractions/10.1216/RMJ-1985-15-2-235.full)* by  Bruce C. Berndt, Robert L. Lamphere, B.M. Wilson.

> Entry 32iii:
> $$
> \zeta(3,x+1):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+k)^3}=\frac{1}{v+1-\frac{1^6}{3(v+3)-\frac{2^6}{5(v+7)-\frac{3^6}{7(v+13)-\ddots}}}}
> $$
> where $v:=2x(x+1)$, and $P(m)=m^2+m+1$ goes $1,3,7,13,\ldots$. One can also rephrase this as
> $$
> \zeta(3,x+1):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+k)^3}=\frac{1}{v+1-\frac{1^6}{3v+(1^3+2^3) -\frac{2^6}{5v+(2^3+3^3) -\frac{3^6}{7v+(3^3+4^3)-\ddots}}}}
> $$

The continued fraction in the original MSE post is this with $x:=1$. As mentioned in the aforementioned [Google site link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0017), $x=0$ yields the well-known continued fraction for $\zeta(3)$ derived from Euler's continued fraction formula (see that link for details).

This continued fraction also plays a starring role in the [Ramanujan Machine's motivation of their recently discovered "conservative matrix field" concept](https://www.ramanujanmachine.com/the-mathematics-of-polynomial-continued-fractions/the-conservative-matrix-field/). They prove this only in the case of positive integer $x$, using so called "coboundary equivalences". I don't particularly like the proof, because their matrices $U_k$ are rather unmotivated, and again only seems to work for integer $x$.

The book I mentioned above, *[Chapter 12 of Ramanujan’s Second Notebook: Continued Fractions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-15/issue-2/Chapter-12-of-Ramanujans-second-notebook-Continued-fractions/10.1216/RMJ-1985-15-2-235.full)*, also provides a full proof, though very complicated (using a bunch of Gamma functions). For reference, I've pasted the first couple lines here:

> Proof. In Entry 35, replace $x$ by $2 x+1$. Then $y=4 x(x+1)+$ $2 m-m^2$, and we need to require that $x>0$. Also let $\ell=n=m$. Noting that $t=0$ and using the second continued fraction of Entry 35, we find that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \frac{1-P}{1+P}= \frac{1-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2+3 m)\right) \Gamma^3\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2-m)\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2-3 m)\right) \Gamma^3\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2+m)\right)}}{1+\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2+3 m)\right) \Gamma^3\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2-m)\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2-3 m)\right) \Gamma^3\left(\frac{1}{2}(2 x+2+m)\right)}} \\
> &=\frac{2 m^3}{y-2 m^3}+\frac{2(1-m)\left(1^2-m^2\right)}{1}+\frac{2(1+m)\left(1^2-m^2\right)}{3 y} \\
> & \quad+\frac{2(2-m)\left(2^2-m^2\right)}{1}+\frac{2(2+m)\left(2^2-m^2\right)}{5 y}+\ldots
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>
> ...

---

Google searches didn't turn up much:

- query "ramanujan continued fraction proof zeta(3)" produced https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/1212.5881 which emphasized that the specialization at $x=1$ is "of crucial importance" in the work of Apéry (indeed, the $x=1$ Ramanujan cfrac is exactly the one that Tito played around with in his MSE post, that ultimately led to Apery's cfrac)
- query "hurwitz zeta function continued fraction ramanujan", Ramanujan's above cfrac seems be pretty much the cfrac in the entry "Wolfgang Berndt and Rotem Elimelech (June 2022)"

---

***Question:* can someone provide a simple proof of this cfrac?** Please motivate, as much as possible at least, any complicated looking formulas that come up (i.e. please don't "pull rabbits out of hats").

Comment: Most of Ramanujan's continued fractions are quite hard to prove, which is why they appealed to GH Hardy. This one might be an exception, but I doubt it.

Comment: @DaveBenson this one just seems so close to the well-known one for $\zeta(3)$ given by Euler’s cfrac formula! It feels like one’s foot is already in the door, tantalizingly close to the cookie jar, but yet unable to open the door completely. I also thought it was a good idea to put the result online with easily searchable key words and a (albeit slim) collection of extant resources

Comment: I'm wondering if the relationship $\zeta(3,x+1)=\zeta(3)-H_x^{(3)}$ can be used to derive the continued fraction for $\zeta(3,x+1)$ from the continued fraction for $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: Perhaps the relationship $\zeta(3,x+1)=-\frac{\psi^{(2)}(x+1)}{2}$ and [this continued fraction](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/10/0005/) for $\psi^{(2)}(z)$ are also related.